# Payment to inactive account

Tags: payments

I have an app running on Stellar which operates a payment system using XLM. My problem is my app cannot send XLM to an inactive account. Is there any ways for me to get my app to be able to send XLM to an inactive account?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `CreateAccount` operation instead of `Payment`.